# Best way to support different processor architectures in native code in Gradle build

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle build that predominantly consists of Java code, which also contains some native code. The native components are published into an Ivy repository (Artifactory). They contain DLLs, LIBs, headers and so forth. These components are currently published using a manual process; I don't yet have a solution that uses Gradle to build the C++ code.

The native components exist in both 32-bit and 64-bit variants, for both release and debug builds. So far I've been publishing them using classifiers such as release-x86, release-x64, etc. (and putting artifacts marked with all classifiers in the same configuration).

I haven't been able to use the classifier to declare dependencies on these components (I asked about this here: [Does Gradle support classifiers for Ivy repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736906/does-gradle-support-classifiers-for-ivy-repositories) but didn't get any answers, I think I failed the first 'S' in SSCCE).

The only way I've found to filter the artifacts is to depend on the configuration that delivers e.g. the DLLs and to then filter the downloaded files by name to get e.g. just the x86 release DLLs (as the classifier is part of it), which seems a bit of a kludge.

I've considered having separate configurations for each combination of x86/x64, release/debug, but it doesn't feel like the right solution. That's four configurations just to encapsulate the DLLs, for runtime dependencies; I'd need four more for the corresponding compile-time dependencies (LIBs, PDBs headers).

Has anyone else achieved this in a way they're happy with?